# Error displaying hyperlinks using hyperref package

Tags: hyperlink

I have issues displaying the hyperlink shown in the following MWE:

`````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,margin=2.5cm,bindingoffset=0.5cm]{geometry} 

\usepackage[hidelinks,colorlinks=true,breaklinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref} 

\usepackage[bidi=basic,layout=lists.tabular]{babel}
\babelprovide[import=ar,mapdigits,main]{arabic}
\babelprovide[import=en,language=Default]{english}

\babelfont{rm}{Latin Modern Roman}
\babelfont[arabic]{rm}{Simplified Arabic}
\babelfont[english]{rm}{Times New Roman}

\title{jhhjjhhj}
\author{}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\chapter{شكر وتقدير} 

\center{profile:{\href{ }{http://www.amazon.de/Frank-Mittelbach/e/B0048S88JK/?_encoding=UTF8&camp=1638&creative=6742&linkCode=ur2&qid=1385935893&site-redirect=de&sr=8-1&tag=wwwlatexproje-21}}}

\end{document}

````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
`````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````

Comment: I think you want `\href{<url>}{<text>}`where `<text>` is the text that is displayed and `<url>` is the URL that is opened upon clicking on `<text>`.  Instead you have `\href{ }{<url>}`

Comment: @peter, I had some issues using this command, It only worked this way with me.

Comment: but it is wrong. The url must be in the first argument.